# why can't lodash find the max value from an array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have below code and I tried to use `lodash` to find the max value from an array object;

```
var a = [ { type: 'exam', score: 47.67196715489599 },
  { type: 'quiz', score: 41.55743490493954 },
  { type: 'homework', score: 70.4612811769744 },
  { type: 'homework', score: 48.60803337116214 } ];
 var _ = require("lodash")

 var b = _.max(a, function(o){return o.score;})
 console.log(b);
```

the output is `47.67196715489599` which is not the maximum value. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 64):

Lodash's [`_.max()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#max) doesn't accept an iteratee (callback). Use [`_.maxBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#maxBy) instead:

```js
var a = [{"type":"exam","score":47.67196715489599},{"type":"quiz","score":41.55743490493954},{"type":"homework","score":70.4612811769744},{"type":"homework","score":48.60803337116214}];


console.log(_.maxBy(a, function(o) {
  return o.score;
}));

// or using `_.property` iteratee shorthand

console.log(_.maxBy(a, 'score'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 14):

Or even shorter:

```
var a = [{"type":"exam","score":47.67196715489599},{"type":"quiz","score":41.55743490493954},{"type":"homework","score":70.4612811769744},{"type":"homework","score":48.60803337116214}];

const b = _.maxBy(a, 'score');
console.log(b);
```

This uses the `_.property` iteratee shorthand.